# Laravel login using JWT

Tags: php, laravel-8

I'm in charge on upgrading Laravel 5 application into latest version, L10. the application itself utilize JWT from LDAP service. Everything works as expected until L7, but in L8 the login mechanism is not working as expected, when trying to login it always redirecting back to the login page (in LDAP service), of course the credential is correct.

Here is the code:

```
public function loginJwt(Request $request)
{
    $secure_random_token = $request->input('validate');
    $token = Cache::pull($secure_random_token);
    if (!$token) {
        throw new AuthenticationException('Validasi request gagal[2]: Token is gone');
    }

    try {
        $payload = JWTAuth::setToken($token)->getPayload();
    } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
        abort(400, $e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        abort(400, $e->getMessage());
    }

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptJwtLogin($request, $token, $payload)) {
        $this->_jwt_tmp = $token;
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }
    return view('auth.failed');
}
```

There is a WARNING in the log:

```
[2023-05-08 14:01:12] local.WARNING: {"username":null,"jwtId":null,"path":"\/","input":[],"method":"GET","originator":["127.0.0.1"],"header":["authorization","cookie","accept"],"exception":{"class":"Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthenticationException","message":"Unauthenticated."}}
```

But that WARNING is also existed in old version. What could go wrong?